# How to change font and font colour of a text from PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script in my php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username']){
echo"Hey".$_SESSION['username'];
echo"<p>";
echo"<a href ='logout.php'>Click here to logout</a>";
}
else
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

But how do you change the font and colour in here: `echo"Hey".$_SESSION['username'];`

I have managed to get it to display a username from the database. But modifying the font and colour of the username doesn't work. I tried using some css elements to wrap around the php tags but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use `printf` for formatting output

Comment: printf? Didn't think PHP could do that. Reminds me of Java and C again lol.

Comment: There's probably a reason it reminds of you of C ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print text color](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16821219/1409082)

Answer (score 2):

Use `span` tag and am sure it will work (Note: Not necessary that we have to use a `span` tag to make it work, any inline element is fine here)

```
echo '<span class="message">Hey '.$_SESSION['username'].'</span>';
```

CSS

```
span.message {
   color: red;
}
```

I guess you must be having some trouble with escaping the quotes, also note that am using `'`, so use `'` if you are passing only literal strings, if you are including `variables` in your string than you need to use `"` else `'` is perfect.

Comment: Ahh that worked. Thanks a lot. Never heard of the <span> tag, I shall check that out too.

Comment: @user11998 `span` is an inline element, it is meant for such purposes, also you can ignore classes on span tag, by having specific CSS selectors

Comment: Might be an idea to get a good reference and brush up on HTML ;)

Comment: @BenM I wonder how people actually start programming PHP and JS/jQuery before having a good knowledge of the markup.. CSS might not be imp for PHP but is surely important for JS/jQuery